# Remap CapsLock key to be Control + Shift + Alt + Super

Tags: capslock

When I was using OS X I remapped my **CapsLock** to **HyperKey** which was a new modifier key. It worked like combination of `Control` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `Super`.

Is it possible in Ubuntu 16.10?